# The Men's Department.

Tags: stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

I was given this question to solve: 
The Men's Department of a large store employs one tailor for customer's fitting. The number of customers requiring fitting has a mean arrival time rate of 24 per hour . Customers are fitted on a first come first served basis and are willing to wait for the tailor's service. The time it takes to fit a customer has a mean of 2 minutes.

1. What is the average number of customers in the fitting room?
2. How much time should a customer expect to spend in the fitting room ?
3. What percentage of the time is the tailors idle?.

This is how I approached the question :
I changed the 2 minutes to hours and had 1/30. Next I solved question one using queuing theory and the solution was 47 customers.
For the second question I had 2 hours per time . 
But I am a bit confused as to how to get the approach in solving the third question. 
Are my answers correct for question 1 and 2. And how will I get the answer to question 3.?

Comment: You could try a Poisson distribution.

Comment: It seems unreasonable to have $47$ customers waiting when the arrival rate is slower than the service rate.  Please check.  For the third, what happens at the end of the day?  You can just take the number of customers received, count the $2$ minutes serving each one, and find the busy time.  Presumably his idle time is the amount of time in the day less the busy time.

Comment: How then will I get the average customers, any idea will be appreciated

Comment: How does a Poisson distribution apply in this case

Comment: Queuing theory is what you want for the average customers, but I don't think you applied it correctly.  If they average $2.5$ minutes between arrivals and $2$ minute service, most of the time he is done with one before the next arrives.  You can't build up a long line.

Comment: Can Someone please provide the appropriate formula or the exact solutions to the question above, your efforts are appreciated.

Comment: @Jam You mean a Poisson *process*, right?

Comment: @Math1000 My mistake.